# I want to download a pdf file which is stored in the folder which is in WebContent of project

Tags: download, struts2, stream, actionresult, http-parameters

This is my `struts.xml` file.

```xml
<action name="sample" class="com.action.getPdf" method="getPdf">
    <result name="success" type="stream">
        <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
       <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param>
        <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${fileName}"</param>
       <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
    </result>
 </action>
```

and this is action code where the object of `File` is getting `null`.

```java
public String getPdf()throws Exception
    {
        Session ss = HibernateUtils.getSess();
        Transaction t=ss.beginTransaction();
        HttpSession httpsession=request.getSession();
        String path2=request.getParameter("path1");
          ServletContext servletContext = ServletActionContext.getServletContext();
        //String path3=servletContext.getRealPath(path2);
        System.out.println("the relative path of  the file is:"+path2);
        try
          {             
            File fileToDownload = new File(path2);   
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileToDownload);                          
          }         
          catch (Exception e)
          {
             if (t!=null) 
             {
                 t.rollback();
                 e.printStackTrace(); 
             }
          }
          finally 
          {
              ss.close(); 
          }         
        return "success";
        }
```

I have stored the file which I want to download in web content folder and I have stored the path of it in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with

```java
String path2=request.getParameter("path1");
```

This method may return `null` if parameter `path1` is missing. If it's not `null` then it should be  a valid path to the readable file that you application has access.

Read the example: [How to read file in Java – `FileInputStream`](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-in-java-fileinputstream/). You can trace the output with the code.

```java
System.out.println("Total file size to read (in bytes) : "
                + getFileInputStream().available());
```

The getter is needed to return a `stream` result, and as you are using dynamic parameter in the result config. You should provide the getter for `fileName`.

Comment: I am getting following exception

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [inputStream] in the invocation stack. Check the <param name="inputName"> tag specified for this action.

Comment: You should have `getFileInputStream()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this question. I have stored the physical path of the file in the data base.For example if your project path is :
D:/Workspace_ABC/SampleProject/WebContent/D-Files/APJ.AbdulKalam.pdf
then store this path as it is in the database table. and then use this path to download file.